# Limit number of database results shown per page in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, limit, truncate

I currently am taking a rails course and on the index page am displaying all the movies stored in the database. I ideally would like to limit this to only show 5 movies and have a navgiation button underneath allowing you to then show more movies if necessary. Here is some of the code that I have for movies.

index.html.erb

```
  <% @movies.each do |movie| %>
    <li>
      <article class="movie">
        <header>
          <%= image_for(movie) %>
          <h2><%= link_to movie.title, movie %> (<%= movie.released_on.year %>)</h2>
          <h3><%= movie.cast %></h3>
        </header>
        <p>
          <%= truncate(movie.description, length: 150, separator: ' ') %>
        </p>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <td><%= movie.rating %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <td><%= movie.duration %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Total Gross</th>
            <td><%= format_total_gross(movie) %></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <footer>
        </footer>
      </article>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  <%= button_to 'View more', root_path, params: { state: :submitted }%>
</ul>
```

controller

```
def index
@movies = Movie.all
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
page = params[:page] || 1
per_page = 10

Movie.limit(per_page).offset(page)
```

Or a [pagination gem](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/pagination).

Comment: How would you then increment the page variable within the button.

`<%= link_to 'View more', movie_page_path(2) %>`

routes

`get 'movies/pages/:page' => 'movies#index', as: :movie_page `

Comment: You can expose a `helper_method` in the controller which returns `params.fetch(:page, 1)`, then in the view `page + 1`, but you are not going to know which is the last page without an additional SQL query to get the total number of records. Which is why it might be better to use a pagination gem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Kaminari gem. https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari

In controller

```
def index
  @moveis = Movie.page(params[:page]).per(5)
end
```

In view

```
<%= link_to_next_page @movies, 'View more' %>
```

You can even achieve this by your own code.

In controller

```
def index
  if params[:previous_page_last_id].present?
    @movies = Moive.where('id < ?', params[:previous_page_last_id]).order('id DESC').limit(5)
  else
    @movies = Moive.order('id DESC').limit(5)
  end
end
```

In view

```
<%= link_to 'View more', movies_path(previous_page_last_id: @moveis.last.id) %>
```